# Where are webaccess dll in tfs2010 ? (WebAccessUserControl)

Tags: c#, dll, tfs

We have created a plugin for webaccess 2008.  The problem is that we are trying to upgrade our version with the one use with tfs2010 but we cannot find the dll that we were using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Webaccess.

Can anybody help us on that ?

I check documentation on google and on msdn but a cannot find anything useful ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dll was in the gac but i did not know that we can copy it directly from the GAC when in command prompt.

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/wellink/archive/2006/07/12/12947.aspx